# Square brushes in Photoshop have one rounded corner

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, brush

I'm trying to create a favicon in Photoshop CS5 by painting individual pixels. I've tried using the square brushes but for some reason each square brush preset has one rounded corner in the bottom right. The hardness settings are 100% and also greyed out.

[image]

How can I get the square brushes to go back to being perfectly square and full hardness so it doesn't bleed into neighboring pixels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Pencil Tool. At 1 pixel the Pencil Tool will give you a single, precise, pixel.

Comment: I also need the eraser tool, so that I can delete pixels and keep them transparent. Is there an alternative to the eraser? (Eraser brushes have same issue as regular brush tool)

Comment: You can simply set the Eraser Tool to "pencil" as well. The Eraser has three basic forms - block, brush, pencil - it can be changed in the Control Bar with the Eraser Tool selected.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you learn how to make your own brushes for exactly these types of instances.

http://danidraws.com/2007/01/20/make-your-own-photoshop-brushes/

You'll find yourself building them regularly as they can be more useful that the default ones. Over the years I've actually ended up using custom brushes as more of a way to drop clipart into a comp quickly. For instance, I have various brushes that are in the shape of the facebook logo, twitter logo, ect ect.

It's an all around important photoshop lesson to learn

Comment: The whole reason I ended up asking the question is that I tried to create my own square brush and it ended up with one rounded corner. Then all the default square brushes had a rounded corner too. So I was able to use the pencil to do what I want, but I still have no idea how to remove the one rounded corner.